# Why can't my script find the files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I made a batch script that should echo the full path of all files with the `.txt` extension.

```
forfiles /m *.txt /c "echo @PATH"
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Could it just be that there are no `.txt` files in that directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
forfiles /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @PATH"
```

The problem is that `echo` is not a program in itself, but is a built-in command of the `cmd` program. So you have to execute `cmd` to use `echo`.